# AVD Error in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I was using android studio happily, after replacing HDD to SSD and installing latest version of android studio, suddenly i couldn't use virtual devices.

I can create any device with any api i want (x86 or x86_64) but after i run my application in it or starting it with AVD Manager, i asked to type password (wtf, i just created my avd), and no matter what i give as input, it always redirected to a page below but "PHONE RESET" button won't do anything:

[image: screenshot of problem]

I tried many things:

- Uninstall and install Android Studio
- Remove old SDK and download SDK from google(through Android Studio) and install it again
- Wipe data, delete and create multiple AVDs
- Download API image inside AVD Manager

Log in terminal is like this:

```
D:\Workspace\New\tools>emulator -avd  Nexus_6_API_26
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: No error
none.xml:3: parser error : AttValue: " or ' expected
<html lang=en>
           ^
none.xml:3: parser error : attributes construct error
<html lang=en>
           ^
none.xml:3: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag html line 3
<html lang=en>
           ^
none.xml:3: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
<html lang=en>
           ^
```

I have windows 10 and Android Studio 3.1.2 and Gradle 4.4 
If anyone else having same issue, please leave a comment to find out what's the similarity between those to tackle the problem. thanks.

Comment: I got the same error, what have you done to tackle this problem?